# Get Last Value Before zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have this table in SQL Server:

```
Cell1   Cell2   Cell3   Cell4   Cell5   Cell6   vbzero

3        65      **12**  0        0       0       
12        4        5      1       6      8  
10        0        0      0       0       0 
1        90        0      0       0       0
```

I want get Last Value Before zero. for example in row one get 12 , and in row two get 8 because row tow don't containt zero and for row3 get 10 ,...

How can Do this in SQL Server .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like ...

```
SELECT COALESCE( NULLIF(Column3, 0) , NULLIF(Column2, 0) , NULLIF(Column1, 0) )
FROM TableName
```

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(Cell1 INT,Cell2 INT,Cell3 INT,Cell4 INT,Cell5 INT,Cell6 INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(3 ,  65  , 12, 0 , 0 , 0),       
(12,  4   , 5 , 1 , 6 , 8),  
(10,  0   , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0), 
(1 ,  90  , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0)
```

### Query

```
SELECT COALESCE( 
              NULLIF(Cell6, 0) , NULLIF(Cell5, 0) , NULLIF(Cell4, 0) 
             ,NULLIF(Cell3, 0) , NULLIF(Cell2, 0) , NULLIF(Cell1, 0)
               )
FROM @TABLE
```

### Result

```
12
8
10
90
```